# bootstrap make divs overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to achieve below layout using bootstrap. I am able to do it otherwise but problem occurs on small screens where the middle most box(smallest one) will not appear where it should be, it goes up. so want to try using bootstrap.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IadmY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to share code, when asking questions.

Comment: something like this        https://jsfiddle.net/0kbkn9d2/1/

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't provide a solution for this specific issue. You'd be better off making it work with your custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Following should generate your desired layout. Add borders or other fancy styles as you want.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}

.main-cover {
  width: 90%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  margin: -60px auto 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: brown;

}

#dp {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -10% 0 0 -10%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dp-pic {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-cover">

</div>
<div class="main-cover">
  <div id="dp">
    <img class="dp-pic" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9e39276ad39fe3cda7ac61dd0f1560dc5ad1ab95/68747470733a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f7875736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f752f3737343835392f4769744875622d5265706f732f7465737464756d6d792f63726173687465737464756d6d792e6a7067">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this solution. I have made few changes in your code.

please have look carefully

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f01ux4f0/)**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
}

.top-cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('IMG_0044.JPG');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.main-cover {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    height: 700px;
    left: 5%;
    top: -60px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: brown;
    border: solid 5px green;
}

#dp {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: -10%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

.dp-pic {
    width: 20vw;
 min-width: 75px;
 max-width: 150px; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: -8%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="top-cover">

</div>

<div class="main-cover">
    <div id="dp"></div>
    <img class="dp-pic" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9e39276ad39fe3cda7ac61dd0f1560dc5ad1ab95/68747470733a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f7875736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f752f3737343835392f4769744875622d5265706f732f7465737464756d6d792f63726173687465737464756d6d792e6a7067">


</div>
```